# Hibernate many to many - join table is not filled on save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class A{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer aId;    

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_to_B",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "aId", referencedColumnName = "aId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bId", referencedColumnName = "bId")})
    private Set<B> bList;
```

and I have the B class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class B {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "bId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;
    }
```

No referenct of A in B.

I have the following code:

```
List<A> someAs = .... // Generated
B b = ... // also generated
b.setAList(someAs);

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
for (A a : someAs) {
    session.save(a);
}
session.save(b);
session.close();
```

The result is All the A instances are saved. the B instance saved too.
But the join table is not filled so if query for the B instance with left join fetch... I get empty A list.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined `A` as the owning side of the relationship by using `@JoinTable`, you will have to add the `B` instances to `A` in order for them to be saved in the join table:

```
a.setBList(someBs);
```

Alternatively, you can change the owning side to `B` and leave the code as it is.